# Race condition with "openstack overcloud node import --introspect --provide <file>" in Victoria?

Tags: openstack, centos8, tripleo

I'm trying to execute `openstack overcloud node import --introspect --provide <file.json>` on a fresh install, but consistently getting

```
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: INFO Starting introspection of node 1a496655-4a8e-4600-afce-97d5dd6d9ae9
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: ERROR Node 1a496655-4a8e-4600-afce-97d5dd6d9ae9 can't start introspection because: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: https://10.100.4.7:13050/v1/introspection/1a496655-4a8e-4600-afce-97d5dd6d9ae9, Invalid provision state for introspection: "verifying", valid states are "['inspect failed', 'inspect wait', 'manageable', 'inspecting', 'enroll']"
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: INFO Starting introspection of node 14225574-e0c8-4c77-bec1-0d52e4525b08
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: ERROR Node 14225574-e0c8-4c77-bec1-0d52e4525b08 can't start introspection because: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: https://10.100.4.7:13050/v1/introspection/14225574-e0c8-4c77-bec1-0d52e4525b08, Invalid provision state for introspection: "verifying", valid states are "['inspect failed', 'inspect wait', 'manageable', 'inspecting', 'enroll']"
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: INFO Starting introspection of node 28c024f8-3b22-46e2-9c8c-661329fcc9c9
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection: ERROR Node 28c024f8-3b22-46e2-9c8c-661329fcc9c9 can't start introspection because: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: https://10.100.4.7:13050/v1/introspection/28c024f8-3b22-46e2-9c8c-661329fcc9c9, Invalid provision state for introspection: "verifying", valid states are "['inspect failed', 'inspect wait', 'manageable', 'inspecting', 'enroll']"
Mar 11 16:59:27 victoriadirector platform-python[353569]: ansible-os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection os_tripleo_baremetal_node_introspection ERROR Introspection completed with failures. 3 node(s) failed.
```

By the time I dump the node list

```
(undercloud) [stack@victoriadirector ~]$ openstack baremetal node list
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
| UUID                                 | Name      | Instance UUID | Power State | Provisioning State | Maintenance |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
| 1a496655-4a8e-4600-afce-97d5dd6d9ae9 | os1srvp03 | None          | power off   | manageable         | False       |
| 14225574-e0c8-4c77-bec1-0d52e4525b08 | os1srvp04 | None          | power off   | manageable         | False       |
| 28c024f8-3b22-46e2-9c8c-661329fcc9c9 | os1srvp05 | None          | power off   | manageable         | False       |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

the `Provisioning State` is "manageable", which suggests that it's attempting to invoke introspection before it's completed "verifying".

I'm testing Train, Ussuri and Victoria, and this is only occurring in Victoria at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like openstack-ironic-inspector.service is not running properly or You have blocked ports. Check if openstack-ironic-inspector.service is running correctly

Comment: Does Victoria release have a bug? YES / NO